# Folders are not shown under root directory when use 'root' in parents when using Google Drive api files list

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I just wanted to see folders and files under root directory when i set ‘root’ in parents in Q, but I can see only one file titled “Get started” pdf file. (I used C# code)

Where are my folders?

But I can see folders when I search by name (ex. name=’Folder1′) in the code.
Also I can see the folder output when I use Api test called “Try this API” which is on API help website (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list).

So only C# code does not show folders?
Can you please tell me why it shows only files, not folders?

FYI: I authenticated using service account and used Google Drive v3 SDK.

Comment: @Srusti Thakkar This is the issue occurred when I use 'root' in parents in Q

Answer (score 1):

If the only file you are seeing is “Get started” pdf file that is a sure sign that you are using a service account for authentication.

Service accounts are not you.  Think of it as a dummy user it has its own google drive account which by default has no files.

Options:

1. Upload files to the service account using the [files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create) method
2. Share a folder on your personal google drive account with the service account. You do this by taking the service account email address and sharing a folder with it.  Note: to my knowledge you cant share your personal root folder with anyone.

Tip: If you are allowing the service account to upload files to your personal google drive account remember to have it grant your personal user permissions to access the files using [permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create)  method or you are going to have files on your drive account that you dont have permissions to access.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you mentioned, I cannot share root folder to the service account. Except root folder, everything worked.
If I create OAuth 2.0 client ID or API Key instead of service account, I think, i solve the issue. But it calls GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.. This is also problem.
Is there any other way to skip GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker authentication when using OAuth 2.0 client ID or API Key instead of service account?

Comment: API key is for public data which wont work unless you can set your root dir to public a bad idea for a lot of reasons and cant be done.    Oauth2 is going to require that you pop up the authentication window and request access of the user.   I suggest you create a directory (NotRoot) on your drive account move everything into that.  Then share NotRoot with the service account, its messy but works.

Comment: Btw for the fun of it i just hit up someone at Google asking why we cant share root  its annoying

Comment: Thank for your clarification. I will ask you again when I have new question.

Comment: And please post here when you get answer that why we cannot share root.

Comment: I doubt they will tell me their reason but i will add it here if they do.   I think the best we can hope for would be a feature request for adding it.

Comment: One question more, I created Non-Root directory and shared to my service account. The folder name is "MyRoot". I guess there may be another directories that has same name with this one.. (ex. /MyRoot/Folder1/Folder2/MyRoot)
The aim is to get FileID of MyRoot (first level folder), but if we use name='MyRoot' in Q, we will have 2 result. How can I solve this problem?
For now as you know, we cannot list folders and file in root, so getting MyRoot without duplication is possible?

Comment: probably something like his mimeType == ‘application/vnd.google-apps.folder’ ‘root’ in parents

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this question is answered or not, so I am replying. I was facing the issue when I was using `name='root'`. It was returning me the list of files and folders but some were missing.

I found somewhere and modified the 'Q' string with the following and it is now showing me the right information.

```
('root' in parents)
```